# How do I use Control.Invoke if I need to pass in a mixture of reference and value types?

Tags: winforms, invokerequired

How do I do something like the following?

```
private delegate void RenameOperation(string name, string uniqueName, int position);

private void AssignColumnNames(string name, string uniqueName, int position)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[position].HeaderCell.Value = name;
    dataGridView1.Columns[position].HeaderCell.Tag = uniqueName;
}
    void SomeFunction()
    { 
    int colCount = 0;
    // ... some other code
    if (dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            RenameOperation rename = new RenameOperation(AssignColumnNames);
            dataGridView1.Invoke(rename, member.Name, member.UniqueName, colCount);
        }
    }
```

Each time I do this I get Object of type 'System.Int32[]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32' and I don't know how to solve my problem at all. I could probably code this very differently but I'm interested in why I can't do this.

Comment: the second parameter of Invoke is an object array of parameters.. see here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb.aspx

Comment: hey, the compiler implictly converts any list of params to object[] so the two statements are actually equivalent. If it helps, I was getting the same exception using object[] :(

Comment: The runtime seems to think that colCount is an int[], not an int.

Comment: if this above comment fixed your problem, then post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @Richard1987: It's because the inferred type of `new[] { colCount }` is `int[]` (since `colCount` is an `int`), and that doesn't match the target type of `object[]`, which causes your `int[]` to be treated as a regular parameter in the context of the `params` keyword, which means it's wrapped inside an `object[]`. Only if you pass a compatible array will `params` not wrap it into its own array. Insted, you should have written `dataGridView1.Invoke(new ResizeOperation(AddColumn), colCount);`

Answer (score -1):

Managed to solve my own problem here - for anyone who is interested I had passed colCount into invoke between declaring it and calling this invoke, but had written: dataGridView1.Invoke(new ResizeOperation(AddColumn), new[] { colCount }); because I thought the type information there was redundant.